# Salesforce Email logs

Tags: salesforce

How do I know what email was sent on the email logs? 
What does the Internal Message ID means?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The internal message number can be used by someone on your email team to track the message in your server. For example, if I track an internal message number it will tell me our message number, who it was received by and the SMTP response. Here's an example of one we traced.

Message 21214687 to someone@cray.com received remote SMTP response '2.0.0 w6IGslsdC015369 Message accepted for delivery'.